# Nativescript how to overflow hidden child

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to create a layout that uses border radius to wrap it's children, but I'm not able to hide the children content within the parent that contains the border radius.

On the web it would be done using `overflow: hidden`, however on the NativeScript I'm not able to do it, this is my `css`:

```
.card {
    border-radius: 10;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 1;
    margin-bottom: 16;
    overflow: hidden;
}

<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of petLista" class="card">
    <StackLayout class="card_image"></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="card_info">
        // ... more content here
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

But when running the app, this is the result:

[image]

What do I need to do to wrap the content within the parent to follow the radius?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try setting `clipToBounds` to equal true on the parent container with the class of `card`

https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_layouts_layout_.layout.html#cliptobounds

Comment: It didn't worked. I'm testing it on android. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you getting an error or any other message? alternatively, maybe try putting it on the child elements?

Comment: No, no errors at all. I also tried putting it on the children but it has also no effect.

Comment: I may have advised you wrong it may be clipToBounds false

Comment: it doesn't work, in iOS when you use border-radius the child elements don't overflow from the container but in android it overflows, no matter if you use clipToBounds="true" in the element with border-radius